# Unit L2 norm of Image in Opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Based on the refrence given in this site,
http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/39541-normalize-to-unit-norm

I tried to do the same in Opencv but I am getting error while doing sparse representation based classification.

So,How to normalize image to have unit L2 norm using Opencv?

Edit:I have written code in this question?

[Sparse representation based classification using opencv,kl1p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576719/sparse-representation-based-classification-using-opencv-kl1p)

And according to http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/132810/PAMI-Face.pdf
I have to take unit l2 norm of image.

Comment: could you show some relevant code bits ?

Comment: double n = cv::norm(image);